# SpriteKit : Need function similar to onEnter and onExit in Cocos2d

Tags: sprite-kit

Cocos2d calls onEnter when scene started and onExit when scene is removed.

```
-(void)onExit
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super onExit];
}
```

Is there any similar method in SpriteKit ?

Comment: Kobold Kit adds node messages called didMoveToParent and willMoveFromParent: https://github.com/KoboldKit/KoboldKit/blob/master/KoboldKit/KoboldKitFree/Framework/Categories/SpriteKit/SKNode%2BKoboldKit.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may override the following methods:

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view;
```

This method is called the moment a scene is loaded onto the view.

```
- (void)willMoveFromView:(SKView *)view;
```

This method is called just before being removed or replaced by another scene.